# jQuery collapse/expand plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

This is my first plugin for JavaScript. It originated from a need for a similar feature at work and I decided to make it a bit more generic in case I needed it again. I was just wanting some criticism on my code. I added comments on the `defaultOptions` to try and give a better picture of what the plugin does. Do I have JavaScript and jQuery standards and best practices down?

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
        // Encase this needs changed due to conflict.
    var dataKey = "_collapse",
        // Plugin instance class
        Collapse = function (options, userEvents) {
            this.options = options;
            this.userEvents = userEvents;
            return this;
        };

    // Plugin's prototype functions
    Collapse.prototype = {
        enable: function (container) {
            var self = this,
                addCollapseButtonToThese = container.find("." + this.options.collapser),
                collapseThese = container.find("." + this.options.collapsee);

            if (collapseThese.length <= 0) {
                console.log("Error: The only children in the container are target children. There is nothing to collapse!");
                return false;
            }

            // Run the addCollapseButton function for each target.
            $(addCollapseButtonToThese).each(function () { self.options.addCollapseButton($(this)); });

            // Add the uncollapsed class to every targetChild.
            collapseThese.each(function () {
                if (!$(this).hasClass(self.options.collapsed) && !$(this).hasClass(self.options.uncollapsed)) {
                    $(this).addClass(self.options.uncollapsed);
                }
            });

            // Enable the click event for the toggle button.
            $(document).on("click", "." + this.options.collapserButton, this.onToggle);

            return true;
        },
        onToggle: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var plugin = $(this).data(dataKey),
                toggleSuccess = Collapse.prototype.toggle(this) > -1,
                events = plugin.userEvents;

            if (plugin === undefined) {
                console.log("Error: Plugin data not found!");
                return -1;
            }

            if (toggleSuccess) {
                // Run user-defined event.
                if (typeof events.onToggle === "function") {
                    events.onToggle(e, this);
                } else {
                    console.log("Error: User-defined event: onToggle is not a function!");
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Error: There was an issue toggling collapse! User-defined event not executed.");
            }
        },
        toggle: function (button) {
            var collapse = $(button).data(dataKey),
                collapsees = collapse.getCollapsees(button);

            button = $(button);
            if (button.hasClass(collapse.options.collapsed)) {
                // Change the button image.
                collapse.uncollapseElement(button);
                button.attr("src", collapse.options.images.uncollapsed);

                $(collapsees).each(function () {
                    collapse.uncollapseElement(this);
                });

                return 0;
            }
            if (button.hasClass(collapse.options.uncollapsed)) {
                // Change the button image.
                collapse.collapseElement(button);
                button.show(); // Keep the button visible.
                button.attr("src", collapse.options.images.collapsed);

                $(collapsees).each(function () {
                    collapse.collapseElement(this);
                });

                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        },
        getCollapsees: function (button) {
            var row = $(button).closest("." + this.options.collapser),
                rows = (this.options.relation === "sibling") ? $(row).siblings() : (this.options.relation === "child") ? $(row).find("." + this.options.collapsee) : $(row),
                index = rows.index(row),
                collapsees = [],
                i = index + 1,
                stop = false,
                collapsee;

            while (!stop && i < rows.length) {
                collapsee = $(rows[i]);
                stop = rows.filter("." + this.options.collapsee).index(collapsee) < 0;
                if (stop) {
                    break;
                }
                collapsees.push(collapsee);
                i += 1;
            }
            return collapsees;
        },
        collapseElement: function (element) {
            $(element).removeClass(this.options.uncollapsed).addClass(this.options.collapsed);
        },
        uncollapseElement: function (element) {
            $(element).removeClass(this.options.collapsed).addClass(this.options.uncollapsed);
        }
    };

    // Public function that enables the plugin.
    $.fn.collapse = function (userOptions, userEvents) {
        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.collapse.defaultOptions, userOptions || {}),
            events = $.extend({}, $.fn.collapse.defaultUserEvents, userEvents || {}),
            plugin = new Collapse(options, events),
            success = false;

        // Initialize the plugin.
        success = plugin.enable($(this));

        // Save a reference of the plugin object
        // Reason: Allow later access.
        // How: Use the data method to keep a copy of the plugin instance with the element.
        // Where: On the collapserButtons.
        $(this).find("." + options.collapserButton).data('_collapse', plugin);

        if (success) {
            plugin.userEvents.onEnable($(this));
        }

        return this;
    };

    // Defaults
    $.fn.collapse.defaultOptions = {
        collapser: "collapser", // CSS class of the container
        collapsee: "collapsee", // CSS class of the items being hidden
        relation: "child", // relation between the collapser and collapsee
        collapserButton: "collapseButton", // CSS class of the toggle button
        collapsed: "collapsed", // CSS class to define the item is collapsed (hidden).
        uncollapsed: "uncollapsed", // CSS class to define the item is uncollapsed.
        addCollapseButton: function (collapser) { }, // function that adds the button
        images: { // image for the button
            collapsed: "Images/collapsed.png", 
            uncollapsed: "Images/uncollapsed.png"
        }
    };
    $.fn.collapse.defaultUserEvents = {
        onToggle: function (e, button) { },
        onEnable: function (container) { },
        onDisable: function (container) { }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I noticed that your options <del>force</del> strongly push the user to provide a CSS class. This doesn't make much sense to me; it seems like just having a selector instead would be better. As is, if a user wants to get something by ID, then they have to use some shenanigans like setting `userOptions.collapser` to `"doesnotexist, #target"`.

  If you do allow arbitrary selectors, then you could perhaps rename `collapsed` to `collapsedClass`, so as to explicitly state it's a class.
- In the anonymous function in `Collapse.prototype.enable()`, you're creating `$(this)` multiple times. This is not good practice; instead, create it once and store it in a local variable, à la `var $this = $(this);`.
- With `collapseEach`, you seem to be adding the `options.uncollapsed` class to anything that does not have it yet, and also does not have the `options.collapsed` class. There's no need to check if it has the `options.uncollapsed` class; jQuery will not add the class twice.
- As a matter of fact, you can simplify this:

  ```
  collapseEach.not("." + self.options.collapsed).addClass(self.options.uncollapsed);
  ```
- `console.log` should be used carefully. In Internet Explorer, the `console` object won't exist unless the Developer Tools are open at load time. Thus, this will throw a `ReferenceError`. Either wrap it in an `if (typeof console !== 'undefined')`, or define it with `var console = console || { log: function(){} };`.
- You've got `true` / `false` for success / failure in `Collapse.prototype.enable()`, but `undefined` / `-1` in `Collapse.prototype.onToggle()`. This feels inconsistent.
- Your `stop` variable in `Collapse.prototype.getCollapsees()` is redundant. You can write it out of the loop condition and just do `if (rows.filter ...) break;`.

Comment: ah, I forgot I still had `console` in there. I was planning on switching it to a `throw`. Would this be better practice?

Comment: And as for the CSS Class vs selector, I previously had a use for it but removed it, so thank you for pointing out I can use any selector now.